# Liaison et enjambement

Tags: grammaire

If enjambment is continuing to read from one line the the next without a pause, does this mean that liaisons should be made between lines as well?

Example from Hugo’s le revenant:

> La mère dont je vais vous parler demeurait
> À Blois

I listened to a couple of readings online that did not make the liaison.

Answer (score 4):

There are [three types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)#Constraints_on_liaison) of liaisons in French: mandatory, impossible and optional.

The liaison in "*demeurait‿à Blois*" is optional (and rare in modern French), that's probably why you didn't find it in online readings.

If the liaison was mandatory it would have been made even with the enjambment.

Comment: Were French poets traditionally even allowed to write poems with mandatory liaisons between lines?

Answer (score 1):

https://fripou.forumgratuit.org/t2684-la-liaison-prosodie

This site suggests that liaison should not be made between lines.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Salut Moidenouveau, this would benefit from 
more explanation than just a link. Link-only answers are not encouraged as they do not really answer the question, and links can rot.